# Escape from html %20

Tags: python, string, escaping, format-string

I'm working on something in Python and I need to escape from %20, the space in a URL. For example:

```
"%20space%20in%20%d--" % ordnum
```

So I need to use %20 for a URL but then %d for a number. But I get this error:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I know what the problem is I just don't know how to escape from a %20 and fix it.

Comment: What is the % operator doing in this snippet? Not a python user-->

Comment: @notJim: It is equivalent to `sprintf("%...", ordnum)` in other languages

Comment: @notJim: It looks like it imports the number on the right side into the string on the left side at %d. Also, not a python user. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to double the `%` characters:

```
"%%20space%%20in%%20%d--" % ordnum
```

but a probably better way is using [`urllib.quote_plus()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus):

```
urllib.quote_plus(" space in %d--" % ordnum)
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I was trying to escape with the backslash. Silly me 0.o

Comment: urllib.quote_plus will actually replace white space with '+' instead of %20 (hence the 'plus' in quote_plus) which causes problems in some examples. If you want %20 use urllib.quote instead.

Answer (score 4):

The %20 should look like %%20 when Python's formatter sees it.  To Python, %% formats out to %.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> unquoted = urllib.unquote("%20space%20in%20%d--")
>>> ordnum = 15
>>> print unquoted % ordnum
 space in 15--
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three ways to solve this:

1. Escape the *%*.

   ```
   "%%%20dogs" % 11
   ```
2. Use the new *.format* syntax.

   ```
   "{}%20dogs".format(11)
   ```
3. Use the + sign instead of *%20*, as I think that's possible as well.

   ```
   "%+dogs" % 11
   ```